# How to git 're-'pull in server?

Tags: git, git-pull

I've just finished a function, add it and commit it in develop branch. When time came to add my work to server, I logged in with ssh, and i did : git pull origin "wrong branch". my web site took an old update, now i've re-pull with develop (which the correct branch) and nothing changes.

How can i fix it please ?

Here is the response I get :

```
From 193.108.29.147:/var/git/repositories/my_website
* branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong branch must be ahead of the correct branch. This means that pulling the wrong branch *also* pulled the correct branch. You probably want to get rid of those extra commits.

Type `git log` and find the commit you've made for your function. Then run `git reset --hard [sha of your commit]` (make sure you don't have any uncommited changes!). Then run `git pull [correct branch]`.

Done